# Generic List data insert in C#

Tags: c#, list, generic-list

I just want to insert some data from a datatable to a list.

Here is my class:

```
class WhereColumnValue
{
    private string columnName;

    public string _columnName
    {
        get { return columnName; }
        set { columnName = value; }
    }

    private string setValue;

    public string _setValue
    {
        get { return setValue; }
        set { setValue = value; }
    }

    private bool setValueStatus;

    public bool _setValueStatus
    {
        get { return setValueStatus; }
        set { setValueStatus = value; }
    }
}
```

Now i have a list of WhereColumnValue type.

```
List<WhereColumnValue> lstWhereColumnValue = new List<WhereColumnValue>();
```

How could I insert data to this lstWhereColumnValue?

I have tried following code:

```
foreach (DataRow tmp in dtAllColumnData.Rows)
            {
                lstColumn.Add(tmp["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
                lbTableColumns.Items.Add(tmp["COLUMN_NAME"]);
                lstWhereColumnValue.Add(***);

            }
```

I have to add an item here(***). but i only have value for _columnValue. Rest two will remain null. how would i do this?

Comment: decoyer..Are you missing some code.. what is lstColumn and lbTableColumns???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your class and add filled-out instances of it to your list.  Something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow tmp in dtAllColumnData.Rows)
{
    WhereColumnValue val = new WhereColumnValue();
    val._columnName = tmp["COLUMN_NAME"];
    val._setValue = tmp{"SET_VALUE"];
    ....
    lstColumn.Add(val);
}
```

You may also want to follow naming conventions and have your properties be ColumnName, SetValue, etc.

Comment: Thanks @zimdanen. Now i want to get the values of  the list. i can imagine a foreach loop. but how can i access each row of the list and get the value of _columnName,_setValue,...?

Comment: The values of the list that you created? Simple access using dot notation: `foreach (WhereColumnValue col in lstColumn) { Process(col._columnName, col._setValue); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
lstWhereColumnValue.AddRange(
            dtAllColumnData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                           .Select(x => new WhereColumnValue() {_columnName = x["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString()})
                           .ToList());
```

Explanation:

This will iterate all rows in dtAllColumnData, for each row create a new `WhereColumnValue` and assign the value of "Column_Name" to the `_columnName` property.

Answer (score 0):

So what is `lstColumn` and `lbTableColumns`?

Since you have declared and initialzed one `List<WhereColumnValue>`, i will use that:

```
List<WhereColumnValue> lstWhereColumnValue = new List<WhereColumnValue>();
foreach (DataRow tmp in dtAllColumnData.Rows)
{
    WhereColumnValue wcv = new WhereColumnValue{
        _columnName = tmp.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME") // maybe more fields here
    };
    lstWhereColumnValue.Add(wcv);
}
```